# Error expected expression before “)” token in C

Tags: c

I get this error(Error expected expression before “)” token in C) when i try to dynamically create a 2-d array of structures

```
       typedef struct
         {
           unsigned char r;
           unsigned char g;
           unsigned char b;
         } pixeli;       
int main()
 {  
    pixeli **rgb=(pixeli**)malloc((sablon_w)*sizeof(pixel*));
    for(int i=0;i<sablon_h;i++)
     rgb[i]=(pixeli *)malloc(sablon_h*sizeof(pixel));
 }
```

Comment: `pixel` or `pixeli`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is typo in both `sizeof` parenthesis: should be `pixeli` instead of `pixel`.